# Slow requests using Heroku in conjonction with Mongo Atlas, and only in this case

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I have an Heroku app communicating with a Mongo Atlas cloud database.

When I run my app outside Heroku with the same database, I have normal request performance, so that rules out any database configuration issues or indexes issues.

When I run my app on Heroku with another Mongo provider, I have normal request performance, so that rules out any Heroku configuration issues or dyno formation issues, as well as application issues.

I've done extensive testing on every combinations.

But when I run my Heroku app in conjunction with the Mongo Atlas database, even making sure that both of them are in the same region, I got many slow requests (sometimes normal, but most of the time 2-3 times slower which is huge).

**In essence, the only setup in which slow requests arise is when the Heroku App communicates with Mongo Atlas (both being on the same region). Replace Heroku with another hosting provider or Mongo Atlas with another Mongodb cloud provider and everything works fine.**

I'm quite puzzled by this issue and I've searched for answers as usual on the Web, but found absolutely no lead yet.

I thought about "noisy neighbours" on Heroku, but that theory is ruled out by the fact that I my app performs normally on Heroku with another database than Mongo Atlas.

So I'm asking a new question in hope for a clue. Is there a known issue between Heroku and Mongo Atlas? Any idea what might cause my problem?